# Tabs to be loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this page as you can see in image.
[image: My page]
this page contains three tabs. I want these tabs to work with AJAX. so I want they to be opened if user clicks on these tabs (not by direct address). but these tabs have forms as you can see the backup form. I want when user clicks on submit button, if posting data is successful, the page comes back to this tab (for example to backup tab). because of working with AJAX, it doesn't work like what I want and also doesn't show me anything in response div. It seems that submitSearchForm function doesn't work at all!! can you please tell me what's wrong?

**My HTML is:**

```
<form name="backupForm" action="backup/" method="POST" id="backupSubmit">
   //my form fields are here
  <p><input type="submit" onclick="submitSearchForm('backupSubmit')"  value="دانلود"  id="sendButton" style="margin-bottom:10px; cursor:pointer;></p>
<div class="response" style="height: auto;></div>
```

**My AJAX function:**

```
function submitSearchForm(id){
                event.preventDefault();
                var temp = $("#"+id).serialize();
                validateForm();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:temp,
                    url:'/backup/',
                    success:function(data){
                        $(".response").slideDown(800).html(data);
                    }
                });
```

and my code in views.py:

```
def backup(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method=='POST':
            variables = RequestContext(request,{})
            return render_to_response('backup.html',variables)
        else:
            return render_to_response('backup.html')
    else:
        return render_to_response("show.html", {
            'str': "bad Request! :(",
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
backup = login_required(backup)
```

EDIT:
I have a page called base.html. in this page I've created the tabs and when one tab is clicked, the url of that tab is called. all my three tabs have their own page. they aren't in the same page.)

**base.html**

```
{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( '#backup_list' ).click( function() {
                $('#firstRemove').remove();
                $( '#backup' ).html( 'waiting ...' ).load( '{% url backup %}');
            });
            $( '#restore_list' ).click( function() {
                $('#firstRemove').remove();
                $( '#restore' ).html( 'waiting ...' ).load( '{% urlrestore %}');
            });
            $( '#expert_question' ).click( function() {
                $('#firstRemove').remove();
                $( '#expertQuestion' ).html( 'waiting ...' ).load( '{% url expertQuestion %}');
            });
        });
        $( document ).ajaxStart( function() {
            $( '#loading' ).fadeIn(400);
        }).ajaxStop( function() {
                    $( '#loading' ).fadeOut(400);

                });
    </script>
```

{% endblock %}

```
        <div id="dRtabs">
            <ul class="tabber">
                <li><a id="backup_list" href="#backup">backup</a> </li>
                <li><a id="restore_list" href="#restore">restore</a> </li>
                <li><a id="expert_question" href="#expertQuestion">Expert Question</a> </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="backup" class="tabContent">
                <div id="firstRemove">
                    {% block mSettings_body %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="restore" class="tabContent">
                loading...
            </div>
            <div id="expertQuestion" class="tabContent">
                loading...
            </div>
        </div>
```

what should I do if I want whenever the page is loaded, it loads the first tab by default?
EDIT2:
I call validateForm function before jQuery.ajax and in this function I call the other three function to check form validating like this:

```
function validateForm()
    {      
        validateStartDate();
        validateEndDate();
        validateCheckbox();
    }
```

and i check that user doesn't leave these fields blank.
for example some thing like this for validateStartDate():

```
function validateStartDate()
    {
        var x=document.forms["backupForm"]["startDate"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
//            alert("Start date must be filled out");
//            or show a hidden label with this error
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but it alerts and after that the code in success function executes! I don't know why it is like this, while I write in code to force it return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is you are not actually preventing your form from submitting, which is necessary in order for your AJAX code to be executed. `event.preventDefault()` only works when you pass the `event` object into the function.

This will work:

```
$(function() {
  $('#sendButton').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var temp = $("#backupSubmit").serialize();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: temp,
          url: 'backup/',
          success: function(data) {
              $(".response").slideDown(800).html(temp);
              console.log(data);
          }
      });
  });
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G722S/5/

In the `success` function you need to put all the code that should be executed after they submit the form. Your html should look something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="tab1" class="tab">Tab1</a>
<a href="#" id="tab2" class="tab">Tab2</a>
<a href="#" id="tab3" class="tab">Tab3</a>

<div class="content" id="page1">
   <!-- content that should show when you click tab1 -->
</div>

<div class="content" id="page2">
   <!-- content that should show when you click tab2 -->
</div>

<div class="content" id="page3">
   <!-- content that should show when you click tab3 -->
</div>
```

Then for your js you'd want something like

```
$(function() {
 $('.tab').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    the_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tab","page");
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#'+the_id).show();
 });
});​
```

And dont forget this css:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #page2, #page3 {display:none;}​
</style>
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zbpp/3/

> what should i do if i want whenever the page is loaded, it loads the first tab by default?

In base.html, change this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#backup_list' ).click( function() {
```

to this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#backup' ).html( 'waiting ...' ).load( '{% url backup %}');
    $( '#backup_list' ).click( function() {
```

Comment: really really thanks. i edit my question. would you mind please helping me? and also what do you mean by "In the success function you need to put all the code that should be executed after they submit the form."? shouldn't i process these data in my views.py? (i'm writing in django.)

Comment: i have a function that i call it like this: <form onsubmit="return validateForm()"> it works well before, but now that $('#sendButton').click(function(e) {...} works, it doesn't work any more and i'm confusing why?!!

Comment: see how the success() function passes in `data`? That contains the response from views.py. Looking at your code, it looks like `data` will return whatever is in backup.html. ill update the question to answer your 2nd question.

Comment: The reason that `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` no longer works is because you are running preventDefault() on the click of the submit button, clicking it no longer submits the html form, but rather creates an ajax request. You need to handle any extra validation in the `$('#sendButton').click` function before the ajax request.

Comment: i don't know how to appreciate you. really thanks. one more question: i did as you say and call validateForm() before ajax request. it works as i've written in validateForm() function. but i want to know although it's not validated (fore example a field is left empty), why it executes the code in success function? why is it suposed to be successful while it isn't actually.

Comment: in validateForm() you need to execute `return false` if its invalid. let me know if that works. if it doesn't please post the code.

Comment: aha, i'll do it, but my code is at my work office and i'll be there about 10 hours later. i'll test it then, and i'll write the result here. thank very very much for your useful answers :)

Comment: i edited my question. 'if block' executes. it seems return false doesn't execute, although its above line(alert) executes! thanks so much :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16738/discussion-between-cooper-maruyama-and-user1597122)